# Why does my query using a MinHash analyzer fail to retrieve duplicates?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, duplicates, elasticsearch-py, minhash

I am trying to query an Elasticsearch index for near-duplicates using its [MinHash implementation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-minhash-tokenfilter.html).
I use the Python client running in containers to index and perform the search.

My corpus is a JSONL file a bit like this:

```
{"id":1, "text":"I'd just like to interject for a moment"}
{"id":2, "text":"I come up here for perception and clarity"}
...
```

I create an Elasticsearch index successfully, trying to use custom settings and analyzer, taking inspiration from the [official examples](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/master/examples/bulk-ingest/bulk-ingest.py) and [MinHash docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-minhash-tokenfilter.html):

```py
def create_index(client):
    client.indices.create(
        index="documents",
        body={
            "settings": {
                "analysis": {
                    "filter": {
                        "my_shingle_filter": {      
                        "type": "shingle",
                        "min_shingle_size": 5,
                        "max_shingle_size": 5,
                        "output_unigrams": False
                        },
                        "my_minhash_filter": {
                        "type": "min_hash",
                        "hash_count": 10,          
                        "bucket_count": 512,      
                        "hash_set_size": 1,       
                        "with_rotation": True     
                        }
                    },
                    "analyzer": {
                        "my_analyzer": {
                        "tokenizer": "standard",
                        "filter": [
                            "my_shingle_filter",
                            "my_minhash_filter"
                        ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "mappings": {
                "properties": {
                    "name": {"type": "text", "analyzer": "my_analyzer"}
                }
            },
        },
        ignore=400,
    )
```

I verify that index creation hasn't big problems via Kibana and also by visiting http://localhost:9200/documents/_settings I get something that seems in order:

[image]

However, querying the index with:

```py
def get_duplicate_documents(body, K, es):
    doc = {
        '_source': ['_id', 'body'],
        'size': K,
        'query': {
            "match": {
                "body": {
                    "query": body,
                    "analyzer" : "my_analyzer"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    res = es.search(index='documents', body=doc)
    top_matches = [hit['_source']['_id'] for hit in res['hits']['hits']]
```

my `res['hits']` is consistently empty even if I set my `body` to match *exactly* the text of one of the entries in my corpus. In other words I don't get any results if I try as values for `body` e.g.

```
"I come up here for perception and clarity"
```

or substrings like

```
"I come up here for perception"
```

while ideally, I'd like the procedure to return near-duplicates, with a score being an approximation of the Jaccard similarity of the query and the near-duplicates, obtained via MinHash.

Is there something wrong in my query and/or way I index Elasticsearch? Am I missing something else entirely?

P.S.: You can have a look at https://github.com/davidefiocco/dockerized-elasticsearch-duplicate-finder/tree/ea0974363b945bf5f85d52a781463fba76f4f987 for a non-functional, but hopefully reproducible example (I will also update the repo as I find a solution!)

Comment: One thing worth noting is that with `min_shingle_size/max_shingle_size: 5`, anything that has less than 5 tokens will not yield anything (e.g. `Spam is delicious`).
Can you also provide a sample search input that you're trying to find duplicates for?

Comment: @Val, thanks for looking into this. Good points, I have edited the question accordingly. The problem reproduces also with longer texts (with many more tokens than in that simple jsonl file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some things that you should double-check as they are likely culprits:

- when you create your mapping you should change from "name" to "text" in your `client.indices.create` method inside `body` param, because your json document has a field called `text`:

  ```
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "text": {"type": "text", "analyzer": "my_analyzer"}
        }
  ```
- in indexing phase you could also rework your `generate_actions()` method following [the documentation](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.streaming_bulk) with something like:

  ```
  for elem in corpus:
    yield {
        "_op_type": "index"
        "_index": "documents",
        "_id": elem["id"],
        "_source": elem["text"]
    }
  ```

  Incidentally, if you are indexing `pandas` dataframes, you may want to check the experimental official library [eland](https://github.com/elastic/eland).
- Also, according to your mapping, you are using a `minhash` token filter, so Lucene will transform your text inside `text` field in hash. So you can query against this field with an hash and not with a string as you have done in your example `"I come up here for perception and clarity"`.
  So the best way to use it is to retrieve the content of the field `text` and then query in Elasticsearch for the same value retrieved. Then the `_id` metafield is not inside `_source` metafield, so you should change your `get_duplicate_documents()` method in:

  ```
  def get_duplicate_documents(body, K, es):
    doc = {
        '_source': ['text'],
        'size': K,
        'query': {
            "match": { 
                "text": { # I changed this line!
                    "query": body
                }
            }
        }
    }

    res = es.search(index='documents', body=doc)
    # also changed the list comprehension!
    top_matches = [(hit['_id'], hit['_source']) for hit in res['hits']['hits']]
  ```